Find a median of two sorted arrays using divide and conquer and recursion
I'm trying to find a median of two sorted arrays, of different sizes, using recursion on a divide and conquer manner. The entry are two sorted arrays and the output is the median of these two sorted arrays.
I am trying to not merge these arrays and then find the median. What I am trying to do is just directly return the median.
Example:

Given I have ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12] and ar2 = [0, 7, 8, 11] the median is 4
Given I have ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12] and ar2 = [0] the median is 2

I know there are many possibilities to solve the problem but I want to do the code using recursion and using a divide and conquer manner.
Moreover, while my code works for some cases, it does not work for the case when one of the arrays have size 1. I would love to have suggestions on how to fix the code for this base case. I can see the problem comes from the first two "ifs" on the code. But if I remove them, I won't have a return for the leaves of the recursion tree, so it won't work for other cases.
import math

def medianOfTwo(L1, L2, l1, h1, l2, h2):

  if (h1 == l1): return L1[l1]
  if (h2 == l2): return L2[l2]

  medL1 = math.floor((l1+h1)/2)
  medL2 = math.floor((l2+h2)/2)


  if(L1[medL1] == L2[medL2]):
    return L1[medL1]
  

  if(L1[medL1] < L2[medL2]):
    return medianOfTwo(L1, L2, medL1, h1, l2, medL2)
  else:
    return medianOfTwo(L1, L2, l1, medL1, medL2, h2)


#ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12] 
#ar2 = [0, 7, 8, 11] 

ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
#ar2 = [7, 8, 11, 12]
ar2 = [0]

print(medianOfTwo(ar1, ar2, 0, len(ar1)-1, 0, len(ar2)-1))


Why is it a problem for your algorithm if you try to split both arrays but don't come to the exact median each time?

Given the input ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12]  and ar2 = [0, 7, 8, 11] and your question title, i would expect the result to be 4, since 4 is in the middle of the sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7,8,11,12] your code produces 3.  Is this the expected answer?

ah, it should be 4 yes :( So I guess I got all wrong. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I don't see any array merging going on in your code at all.  Looks like you're trying to find the median of two sorted arrays.

Yes, I had defined badly the problem. It should be "Find a median of two sorted arrays using divide and conquer and recursion", i edited the post

Also added examples :)

Here's a recursive divide and conquer method that at each level removes the smallest and largest values from the combination of the two arrays. Once there are two or less values remaining, the median result is the smaller of the remaining values (if you want the average, replace min(arr1 + arr2) with sum(arr1 + arr2)/len(arr1 + arr2)).
def median(arr1, arr2):
    if len(arr1 + arr2) <= 2:
        return min(arr1 + arr2)
    if len(arr1) == 0:
        return median(arr1, arr2[1:-1])
    elif len(arr2) == 0:
        return median(arr1[1:-1], arr2)
    if arr1[0] < arr2[0]:
        if arr1[-1] > arr2[-1]:
            return median(arr1[1:-1], arr2)
        else:
            return median(arr1[1:len(arr1)+1], arr2[:-1])
    else:
        if arr2[-1] > arr1[-1]:
            return median(arr1, arr2[1:-1])
        else:
            return median(arr1[:-1], arr2[1:len(arr2)+1])

median([1, 2, 3, 4, 12], [0, 7, 8, 11])
median([1, 2, 3, 4], [0])
median([10], [0, 5, 9, 12])

Output:
4
2
9

It has been pointed out that this is quite inefficient (O(n^2)) due to the need to make array copies. Here is another version which maintains indexes into each array instead, so should be O(n):
def median(arr1, arr2):
    def helper(arr1, arr2, l1, h1, l2, h2):
        if max(h1-l1, 0) + max(h2-l2, 0) <= 1:
            return sum(arr1[l1:h1+1] + arr2[l2:h2+1]) / len(arr1[l1:h1+1] + arr2[l2:h2+1])
        if arr1[l1:l1+1] < arr2[l2:l2+1] or len(arr2[l2:l2+1]) == 0:
            if arr1[h1:h1+1] > arr2[h2:h2+1] or len(arr2[h2:h2+1]) == 0:
                return helper(arr1, arr2, l1+1, h1-1, l2, h2)
            else:
                return helper(arr1, arr2, l1+1, h1, l2, h2-1)
        else:
            if arr2[h2:h2+1] > arr1[h1:h1+1] or len(arr1[h1:h1+1]) == 0:
                return helper(arr1, arr2, l1, h1, l2+1, h2-1)
            else:
                return helper(arr1, arr2, l1, h1-1, l2+1, h2)
    
    return helper(arr1, arr2, 0, len(arr1)-1, 0, len(arr2)-1)

I ran performance testing using perfplot and needless to say @btilly's bisection algorithm is significantly faster. This algorithm also exceeds the maximum recursion depth once the total length of the arrays exceeds ~2,000 entries. Test code:
def setup(n):
    random.seed('median')
    split = random.randrange(n)
    a = random.sample(range(n), k=split)
    b = set(range(n)).difference(a)
    return sorted(a), sorted(b)

b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels = [ median_of_two_sorted_arrays, median ],
    labels = ['bisect', 'shrink'],
    n_range = [2**k for k in range(3, 11)]
)

Here's the chart:


This gives the correct answer, but I don't think you'd ever do this in practice — at least, not if the arrays can be large — because it requires O(n²) time due to making O(n) array copies and so on, and because it requires O(n) stack depth. (By contrast, the simple "merge the arrays and get the median by index" approach requires only O(n) time, and a more carefully optimized approach can handle this in O(log n) time.)

@ruakh Agreed. I was just trying to provide a sample way of solving the problem recursively. You should post an answer, I'd happily recommend OP accept it.

@ruakh I've added a version that maintains array indexes rather than copying the arrays. This should be more efficient.

@Nick This can be done recursively in O(log(n)^2) fairly easily. There are better tricks than just using indexes.

@btilly please, post an answer. I'd be interested in seeing O(log(n)^2), and OP should too.

Thanks for the solution @Nick! Question: if the input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 12]-[0, 7, 8, 11] the algorithm will start with [1, 2, 3, 4] -  [0, 7, 8] since it receives "high" as "arr-1" and test arr1[l1:h1], arr2[l2:h2]. Then, on first interaction, the algorithm will remove '4', '0' because it will call helper(arr1, arr2, l1, h1-1, l2+1, h2). So not the smallest and largest values from the combination of the two arrays, because if it were it will be 0 and 8. It seems the algorithms works anyway, but I'm just trying to figure it out how it works. If you can explain it will be great.

@CatarinaNogueira the arrays are 0-indexed so arr1[len(arr1)-1] == 12 and arr2[len(arr2)-1] == 11. If you add a debug print(arr1, arr2, l1, h1, l2, h2, arr1[l1:h1+1], arr2[l2:h2+1]) at the beginning of the function you'll see the arrays go [1, 2, 3, 4, 12] [0, 7, 8, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4] [7, 8, 11], [2, 3, 4] [7, 8], [3, 4] [7] and finally [4] [] as well as getting to watch the indexes change.

Hi @Nick I asked because did add the prints, that's why I'm lost. So I did add one print for recursive call, so we have (in order of the recursive calls);  print(f'a {arr1[l1+1:h1-1]} -  {arr2[l2:h2]}') ,   print(f'b {arr1[l1+1:h1]} -  {arr2[l2:h2-1]}'),    print(f'c {arr1[l1:h1]} -  {arr2[l2+1:h2-1]}') and         print(f'd {arr1[l1:h1-1]} -  {arr2[l2+1:h2]}') . After the "max" I put       print(f'{arr1[l1:h1+1]} - {arr2[l2:h2+1]}') and what I have is:
d [1, 2, 3] -  [7, 8]
b [2, 3] -  [7]
b [3] -  []
b [] -  []
[4] - []
4

I understand the idea of the algorithm (which is super smart) and the example you just send on  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12] [0, 7, 8, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4] [7, 8, 11], [2, 3, 4] [7, 8], [3, 4] [7] and finally [4] [] but this is not what the prints are giving

Here's an online demo: https://ideone.com/eVeYyj this shows the inputs to the function and the values being tested in each call

@CatarinaNogueira please see my edit - I found a bug in the code with arrays of a total even length.

I've added comparative performance data between the two solutions. As you can see @btilly algorithm is (as expected) much faster. You should accept that answer instead.

Since both arrays are sorted, we should use a binary search. I've commented it because such searches are always finicky, but that's the nature of the beast.
First, here is a completely general solution. It will find an answer in k arrays of size at most n in time O(k^2 log(n)^2). And, if it isn't a pathological example, usually in closer to O(k log(n)^2).
Instead of solving median, it is easier to write a general "find kth rank element". Now we can do a variant of Quickselect - take a pivot as the middle of the range on one array, find where that would go if inserted into all of the others, and thereby learn its rank. If this isn't the answer yet, we can update ranges to filter out everything whose rank is bigger or lesser than that (depending).
Each time we take a pivot in one array, we do O(k log(n)) work to find its rank. After O(log(n)) pivots we've managed to go through one array. So after O(k log(n)^2) work we've processed one array entirely. Hopefully we've cut down on the other arrays by then. But even if we haven't, we just have to do that for all k arrays.
With k=2, this becomes O(log(n)^2).
# This is a useful pattern for recursion. Put a few sanity checks into
# the first call, then call a private recursive function.
#
# Note, since we're asked for recursion, I'm replacing every loop with
# recursion. That's slower than the loop, but it's the principle of the
# thing.

# This will find where a value can go in a sorted array between two bounds.
def _insert_after_in_sorted (value, array, lower, upper):
    if lower == upper:
        return lower
    else:
        mid = (lower + upper) // 2
        if value < array[mid]:
            return _insert_after_in_sorted(value, array, lower, mid)
        elif array[mid] < value:
            return _insert_after_in_sorted(value, array, mid+1, upper)
        else:
            return mid

def _k_before_in_sorted_arrays (k, arrays, lowers, uppers):
    # Get one array.
    array = arrays.pop()
    lower = lowers.pop()
    upper = uppers.pop()

    # Try again if this array was empty.
    if lower == upper:
        return _k_before_in_sorted_arrays(k, arrays, lowers, uppers)

    mid = (lower + upper) // 2
    pivot = array[mid]
    mids = [_insert_after_in_sorted(pivot, *struct)
            for struct in zip(arrays, lowers, uppers)]
    found_before = mid - lower + sum(mids) - sum(lowers)
    if found_before == k:
        # Found it.
        return pivot
    elif found_before < k:
        # mids are next lowers.
        # Put our array back on.
        arrays.append(array)
        mids.append(mid+1) # pivot also is lost.
        uppers.append(upper)
        return _k_before_in_sorted_arrays(
                k - found_before - 1, arrays, mids, uppers)
    else:
        # mids are next uppers
        # Put our array back on.
        arrays.append(array)
        lowers.append(lower)
        mids.append(mid)
        return _k_before_in_sorted_arrays(k, arrays, lowers, mids)



def kth_in_sorted_arrays (k, *arrays):
    arrays = list(arrays) # Was a tuple, need mutable.
    lowers = [0 for a in arrays]
    uppers = [len(a) for a in arrays]
    if k < 1 or not isinstance(k, int):
        raise Exception("k was {k}, should be a positive integer")
    elif sum(uppers) < k:
        raise Exception("k was {k}, we only had {sum(uppers)} items")
    else:
        # Go to private version. Note that k is now k-1, so the number
        # BEFORE the one we want.
        return _k_before_in_sorted_arrays(k-1, arrays, lowers, uppers)

Here is a trivial test.
for i in range(6):
    print(kth_in_sorted_arrays(i+1, [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8]))

And now we can easily write a median.
def median_of_sorted_arrays (*arrays):
    total = sum((len(array) for array in arrays))
    if 0 == total % 2:
        return (kth_in_sorted_arrays(total//2, *arrays) +
                kth_in_sorted_arrays(total//2 + 1, *arrays)) / 2
    else:
        return kth_in_sorted_arrays(total//2 + 1, *arrays)

And a test for that.
print(median_of_sorted_arrays([5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8]))
print(median_of_sorted_arrays([5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8, 9]))

Now in fact for the special case of 2 arrays, we can become much more efficient. Let i be the number of elements from the first array we want before our rank k element. Let's use 2*i for trying to do that with an element from the second array, and 2*i+1 for the first.
The swapping of second and first arrays there is a technical detail to allow all of 0..2*len(array1) to be valid before the index 2*len(array1)+1 runs off the end of the first array.
def _k_before_in_two_sorted_arrays(k, array1, array2, lower, upper):
    # We will index possible answers as follows. If i is the number of
    # elements from array1 before our pivot, then 2*i will be the
    # possible answer array2[k-i], and 2*i+1 will be the possible
    # answer array1[i]. So here is the range.
    mid = (lower + upper) // 2
    i = mid // 2
    move = 0 # This will be what direction to move i
    if k < i:
        # Taking too much from array1.
        move = -1
    elif 0 == mid%2:
        # Looking for array1[i-1] <= array2[k-i] <= array1[i]
        # for everything in bounds.
        if len(array2) < k-i+1:
            # Not enough elements in array2, need i larger.
            move = 1
        elif i < len(array1) and array1[i] < array2[k-i]:
            # Need i larger to increase array1 or decrease array2.
            move = 1
        elif 0 < i and array2[k-i] < array1[i-1]:
            # Need i smaller to decrease array1 or increase array2
            move = -1
        else:
            return array2[k-i] # Works!
    else:
        # Looking for array2[k-i-1] <= array1[i] <= array2[k-i]
        # for everything in bounds.
        if len(array2) < k-i:
            # Not enough elements in array2, need i larger.
            move = 1
        elif 0 <= k-i-1 and array1[i] < array2[k-i-1]:
            # Need i larger to increase array1 or decrease array2.
            move = 1
        elif k-i < len(array2) and array2[k-i] < array1[i]:
            # Need i smaller to decrease array1 or increase array2
            move = -1
        else:
            return array1[i] # Works!

    if move == -1:
        return _k_before_in_two_sorted_arrays(
                k, array1, array2, lower, mid-1)
    else:
        return _k_before_in_two_sorted_arrays(
                k, array1, array2, mid+1, upper)


def kth_in_two_sorted_arrays (k, array1, array2):
    # Sanity checks.
    if k < 1 or not isinstance(k, int):
        raise Exception("k was {k}, should be a positive integer")
    elif len(array1) + len(array2) < k:
        raise Exception("k was {k}, we only had {sum(uppers)} items")

    if len(array2) < len(array1):
        # Swap them.
        (array1, array2) = (array2, array1)
    # We will index possible answers as follows. If i is the number of
    # elements from array1 before our pivot, then 2*i will be the
    # possible answer array2[k-i], and 2*i+1 will be the possible
    # answer array1[i]. So here is the range.
    lower = 0
    upper = 2*len(array1)
    return _k_before_in_two_sorted_arrays(k-1, array1, array2, lower, upper)

As before we can test this rank code.
for
i in range(6):
    print(kth_in_two_sorted_arrays(i+1, [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8]))

Write a median using it.
def median_of_two_sorted_arrays (array1, array2):
    total = len(array1) + len(array2)
    if 0 == total % 2:
        return (kth_in_two_sorted_arrays(total//2, array1, array2) +
                kth_in_two_sorted_arrays(total//2 + 1, array1, array2)) / 2
    else:
        return kth_in_two_sorted_arrays(total//2 + 1, array1, array2)

And quickly test that.
print(median_of_two_sorted_arrays([5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8]))
print(median_of_two_sorted_arrays([5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 8, 9]))

I can't promise that I found all bugs. But this approach is O(log(n)).

@Nick Here you go.  Both a general one of the speed I promised, and a special 2 arrays one that is even faster.

Thanks. Complicated algorithm... I'll take a look at it over the weekend.

@Nick The general algorithm can be made more complicated. I figured out how to make it O(k log(k) log(k*n)).

The special case version was enough! :) It took a while to get my head around the use of i and k-i as indexes. TIL.
